# Отправка результата из игры на сервер

Tags: php, разработка-игр, сервер

Здравствуйте, великие умы (без сарказма). :)

Например, есть куча сетевых игр, где можно играть 1 на 1 через сеть интернет или командами. Так вот можно ли? И если можно, то как реализовать отправку отчета о результате игры (будь то гонки, стрелялки, стратегии) на указанный сервер?
Например, два игрока (один - в Москве, второй - в Питере) решили поиграть в NFS, после того как один из них выигрывает, на указанный сервак отправляется отчет, что такой-то игрок выиграл, придя первым с таким-то временем. Как можно такое реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: А что, у NFS нет серверного варианта игры? Насколько я помню, раньше был (лет 10 назад). )

Comment: NFS я привел в примере, чтоб было понятие, о каких играх идет речь.

Comment: ВыИграл. Не в йгры же йграем, право дело.

Comment: А разве клиент должен за результат отвечать? Я, как злоумышленник, могу подделать запрос и сказать серверу, что выиграл я. И что будет делать сервер, если то же самое скажет мой оппонент?

Comment: уважаемый ВОРОН, но можно же как-то защитить способ передачи данных серверу! и вообще сам клиент от вмешательства таких людей )

Comment: @kiberchainik, вы ни разу пиратских программ не видели? )) Так что при желании клиент спасти не получится. Данные защитить тоже - если у меня есть клиент, значит я могу на живую увидеть как будут формироваться данные, а уж подделать их труда не составит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, в таком случае всегда есть клиент и сервер. Допустим, два клиента создают игру, и на сервере запускается сессия для них, и уже сервер следит за тем, кто победил, а кто нет. Если интересует именно отправка, то это банальный запрос к серверу с нужными данными, которые сервер обработает и по надобности вернет результат клиентам.

Comment: Спасибо за толчок, но тогда вопрос другой: каким образом этот клиент связать с любой игрой, которую будут запускать люди на компах? Как такой клиент-сервер сделать безопасным от злых рук, как писал выше товарищ ВОРОН?

Comment: А еще лучше делать не обычный ajax-запрос, а html5 web-сокеты. А в качестве замены для старых браузеров - использовать long-polling. Подробнее можете ознакомиться тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax-vs-webrtc-vs-server-sent-events

Comment: Спасибо, а какой-то русскоязычный мануал есть? Я не силен в английском.

Comment: Наберите html5 web сокеты в гугле. Я уверен, что что-нибудь будет.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, тут уже нужно писать специальное ПО (если конкретно речь об NFS), которая будет отсылать данные, тут обычным пхп не отделаться, тут глубокие знания нужны.

Что-то типа лаунчера, который будет анализировать память и в случае победы (ведь в памяти победа как-то отображается) отправлять данные.

Comment: Речь идет не только об NFS, я привел эту игру в примере, чтоб было понятие, о каких играх идет речь. Игры могут быть и другие, такие как, например, контр страйк. Главная задача - это отправка результата в конце каждой игры о том, какой игрок или какая команда одержала победу. А память имеется в виду оперативная? Верно?